# set tomcat response header location as absolute path instead of relative path

Tags: spring, nginx, tomcat, http-status-code-404

In my spring application after upgrading to tomcat8 response header location is become relative path. Can i know which file should i config for changing it back to absolute path.

As we are using nginx server and alb in our application. relative path response returning 404 page in nginx url were it is working fine in alb .

Answer (score 0):

Set `<Context useRelativeRedirects="false">` in context.xml of tomcat folder.

Reference :
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html